# Azure pipeline: conditional env variable based on OS

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to make **my environment variables dependent on the Agent operating system**.

I wrote the following `test.yml`, but it does not work:

```yaml
jobs:
  - job: Test
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    steps:
      - pwsh: |
          echo $env:TestVar
          echo $env:OS
        env:
          OS: $[variables['Agent.OS']]
          ${{ if eq(variables['Agent.OS'], 'Windows_NT') }}:
            TestVar: "I am Windows"
          ${{ if eq(variables['Agent.OS'], 'Linux') }}:
            TestVar: "I am Linux"
```

Is there a problem with my YAML indentation?

Comment: Not sure about the conditional part, but you don't really need the `OS` environment variable, you should be able to access `Agent.OS` directly as `$env:Agent_OS`.

Comment: I was just checking if I my expression is correct. I think my [conditional expression is correct](https://github.com/search?q=%22%24%7B%7B+if+eq%28variables%5B%27Agent.OS%27%5D%2C+%27Windows_NT%27%29+%7D%7D%3A%22+language%3AYAML&type=Code), but maybe I cannot use it for `env`

Comment: All looks correct and follows what the docs say too, can you grab the logs of what is happening?

Comment: Here is the [run log](https://dev.azure.com/atomcommunity/atomcommunity/_build/results?buildId=252&view=logs&j=0d2f351d-5899-57e2-0cb5-b37eb91cc930&t=663a9321-0ebe-5e1e-3fb9-5cad6da0bec6&l=12). Nothing useful. `TestVar` is empty. Also, OS is just printed as `$[variables['Agent.OS']]`. I can fix that by using `$(Agent.OS)`, but that is another issue.

Comment: @Amin Your syntax is correct after changing `OS: $(Agent.OS)`. If you change `${{ if eq(variables['Agent.OS'], 'Windows_NT') }}` to `${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master') }}`, the `TestVar` can be printed. It seems agent variable is not supported in such scenario.

Comment: This does not really solve the syntax issue. The azure syntax is still faulty. I used bash environment variables instead of Azure syntax.

Comment: @Amin Check my reply below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the answer of Cece Dong, Agent variables can't be used in this syntax. The cleanest way to achieve the same effect is just to use the shell for managing environment variables.

```yaml
jobs:
  - job: Test
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    steps:
      - pwsh: |
           if ($env:AGENT_OS -eq "Windows_NT") {
             $env:TestVar="I am Windows"
           }
           if ($env:AGENT_OS -eq "Linux") {
             $env:TestVar="I am Linux"
           }
```

and if `TestVar` is supposed to be used in another step use this afterwards:

```
           echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=env:TestVar]$env:TestVar"
```

Answer (score 2):

Your YAML seems to be correct, but there is sth not clear on Azure DevOps. However, you can use this as a workaround:

```yaml
trigger:
- master

jobs:
- job: Test
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  variables:
    varOS: $(Agent.OS)
  steps:
    - pwsh: |
        $testVar = ''
        $os = '$(Agent.OS)'
        if ($os -eq 'Windows_NT') {
          $testVar = "I am Windows";
        } elseif ($os -eq 'Linux') {
          $testVar = "I am Linux";
        }
        Write-Host $testVar
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=HelloOS;isOutput=true]$testVar"
      name: Initialize
    - pwsh: |
        echo $env:TestVar
        echo $env:OS
        echo $env:AGENT_OS
        echo $env:IsMaster
        printenv
      env:
        OS: $(varOS)
        TestVar: $(Initialize.HelloOS)
        ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master')}}:
          IsMaster: "true"
```

for this build I got:

```
I am Linux
Linux
Linux
true
```

I tried few approached, also putting conditional setup in variables section. But only this gave expected result. Of course since you can access `$env:AGENT_OS` you can put this conditional logic directly in target step. I just assumed that you want to have `TestVar` provided somewhere else.

Comment: If I set the env variable using `$env:testVar="Linux"` do I still need to use `task.setvariable` to make it available through other steps? I want to know if the env variables that are set, get lost between the steps.

Comment: IMHO yes, I did not check this, but all pipeline/release/agent/etc variables become env variables, but not otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is correct after changing `OS: $(Agent.OS)`. But Agent variables doesn't support used in a template expression. You could refer to the following link, the variables with `Yes` in `Available in templates?` are supposed to able able to used in a template expression.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: Thanks that's a good explanation of why this does not work. `Agent` variables are not available in this syntax. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#agent-variables